# How to run a shell command on all containers of a replicated docker-compose service?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am running spark workers using docker, replicated using a docker-compose setup:

```
version: '2'

services:
  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:latest
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://1.1.1.1:7077
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 4
```

When I run `docker-compose exec spark-worker ls`, for example, it only runs on usually the first replica. Is there a way to broadcast these commands to all of the replicas?

`docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`

`Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in facility for this, but you could construct something fairly easily. For example:

```
docker ps -q --filter label=com.docker.compose.service=spark-worker |
xargs -ICID docker exec CID ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a simpler command than what @larsks proposed, which leverages the `docker-compose` command itself.

```
SERVICE_NAME=spark-worker
for id in $(docker-compose ps -q $SERVICE_NAME); do
    docker exec -t $id "echo" "hello"
done;
```